# jqGrid filter not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a column model like this;

```
{ name: 'AddressId', index: 'AddressId', key: true, width: 100, editable: false, editoptions: { size: 10 } },
{ name: 'Street Number', index: 'StreetNumber', width: 100, editable: true },
```

So the grid columns are;

AddressId, Street Number

When I filter on the AddressId, all works fine.  When I enter a filter in "Street Number" the filtering comes up with zero results.

If I rename "Street Number" to "StreetNumber", the same as its index value, then the filtering works.

Is there a setting to change this?

**Edit**
The same applies for Grouping.  Works when the name is the same as the index but fails when it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "local"` or some remote `datatype` (`"xml"` or `"json"`) with `loadonce: true` then you **have to have `colModel` with the same `name` and `index` property**. I recommend don't specify any `index` property in the case and specify `name` property only. In the case the `name` value will be copied by jqGrid to `index`.

Second, one should not use `name` property which values contains special meta-characters (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). `name` property will be used to build values of `id` attributes of some internal jqGrid constructions. So one have to escape spaces during every construction of selectors on the elements. Old versions didn't do this. More recent jqGrid versions escaped many meta-characters, but not the space. The current version (4.6) escapes spaces and one can in general use spaces in `name`, but it's strictly not recommended. I don't understand why you chosen `name: 'Street Number'`. One can use any names in `colNames` or in `jsonmap`, but why one could need to use `name: 'Street Number'`?

Comment: OK, So I added a "heading" field to the columnModel and I now use that for the headings.  Thanks as this kinda pointed me in the right direction

Comment: @griegs: You are welcome! You mean probably `label` property in `colModel` and not `heading`?

Comment: No I mean "heading".  Within the grid I then use "colNames: GRID.getGridHeadings()" and the method reads all the "heading" properties, builds the heading string and returns it.  jqGrid allows you to add properties and it ignores them.

Comment: @griegs: You don't need define `colNames` parameter of jqGrid. Instead of that you can define `label` properties in `colModel`. See [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1056-L1060) of jqGrid code.